# asp.net button in UpdatePanel causes whole page refresh in Firefox 15.0.1 when called from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Ok, this is a strange one.

I am using .net framework 4. 
I have an asp.net button within an updatepanel, like this:

```
<asp:Button id="btNacinMontaze" runat="server" class="buttonOIHidden" value="nm" CausesValidation="false" onclick="btNacinMontaze_Clicked" clientidmode="Static" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
```

If I click on it within a browser it works correctly - updatepanel updates itself without refreshing the whole page, correct server events gets triggered.

if i do from within the page this:
    `document.getElementById("btNacinMontaze").click();`

the whole page refreshes and the correct server event gets triggered.

If I issue the same line of code from within the firebug console, just the updatePanel refreshes.

If I load the same page in Chrome or IE9 it works ok in all cases. 
I've tracked what is different between click by mouse and click by code by debugging in Firebug, and saw that in the `Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_doPostBack` method the line

```
if (!this._postBackSettings.async)
```

is different. async is true on click by mouse, and false by code click.

I am out of ideas as to why this happens and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you have [defined an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` for your button](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx)

Comment: I havent, I can look into that. Still, it shouldn't be necessary since it works ok in all other browsers as it is.

Comment: Try not 'clicking' the button, but rather eval the onclick or href code that is generated for it. I have been struggling with this problem in the past also, and if I recall correctly this solved the problem.

Comment: @SliverNinja s response was correct, adding AsyncPostBackTrigger got the thing going.  can you put it in as an answer, so I can mark it?

Comment: Added by request - glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should [define an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx) to stop the entire page refresh.

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btNacinMontaze" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```